# Unable to build a cross platform apps on Xamarin.forms?

Tags: build, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017, android-7.1-nougat

I'm following a [tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/hello-xamarin-forms/quickstart/) to create a cross-platform app using `xamarin.forms`
 except that I'm using Windows 7 and hence I skipped those steps for `UWP` part.

Now when I trying to build the solution, I'm getting the below error message

> 1>  No way to resolve conflict between "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" and "mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e". Choosing "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" arbitrarily.

Based on findings on the net it seems that something to do with versioning messed up however this should not happen as it's a new solution from scratch.

I've also checked the properties that stated as below:

```
- "Compile using android version (Android 7.1(Nougat))"
- Android Manifest "Target Android version" Use compile using SDK version
```

Well to be exact, the build was successful but with error logging as output. Please refer to below image

[image]

May I know what else I can try?

Comment: Click on `Manage Nuget packages for Solution`, Click on the `Consolidate` tab, for every package in the Consolidate tab, update the package to the same version for every project.

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT: There is nothing to be updated at Consolidate tab

Comment: I don't see it as an error. It seems that project builds successfully from you sreenshot

Comment: Have you enable the [Deploy checkboxes](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/windows/visual-studio/troubleshooting/deploy-checkboxes/) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by issuing an `update-package -reinstall` command in the Package Manager Console.

Comment: I've tried your way and successfully reinstalling a lot of packages but when I try to build the solution it still throwing me same error

Comment: Kindly refer to my updated question as Ive included the image of the output

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your Xamarin (Visual Studio) installation version is the same as the Xamarin NuGet packages your using.

I recommend to:

1. Update Xamarin and your Xamarin NuGet packages to the latest versions.
2. Clean (in build menu)
3. Rebuild (in build menu)
4. Try again, if it does not work, continue steps:
5. Update all your Android related installations (using the SDK manager)
6. Check the paths for JDK, SDK and NDK in Visual Studio => Options => Xamarin
7. Try again

It could also be, that you are using a third-party NuGet package that is not compatible with your installed versions. Try removing NuGet packages to isolate the problem.

Unfortunately, there could be many things wrong here, but mostly it is related to versions and installations. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're trying to deploy to a device that does not meet the target requirements.

Verify that the version of the device or emulator you're working on is at least what is shown in your Android Build Options.

To troubleshoot any issues, I'd recommend opening the Android SDK Manager and downloading the Build and SDK tools that match the device you're planning to test on, and rebuild your project targeting the new SDK.

Comment: The message is showing right after build project. It wasn't even being deployed on emulator nor device yet

Comment: Exactly, I'm suggesting a solution to that problem. (not deploying because the device doesn't meet the target framework)